# Error while fetching the full path name of an image in Android

Tags: android, image-processing

In order to send an image to server, while getting the path of the image , the following code is used

```
private String getPath(Uri uri){
        String path = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Beginning of getPath()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String document_id=cursor.getString(0);
            document_id=document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(".")+1);

            cursor=getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+"=?",new String[]{document_id},null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            Toast.makeText(this,"At the end of getPath()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }


        return path;
    }
```

I have set two toast methods here to check the flow of control. I'm getting the first toast message at the beginning of the method but not getting the next one...which reflects the error in the that part of the code...
What might have gone wrong here.
Android stack trace gave the following'

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

at the folowing line

```
path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to send an image to server, while getting the path of the image , the following code is used

That code will not work for arbitrary `Uri` values.

> What might have gone wrong here

You are trying to derive a file path for a `Uri`.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Then, either:

- Use the `InputStream` directly for uploading the content, if your HTTP client API supports that, or
- Use the `InputStream` and a `FileOutputStream` (on some file that you control, such as in `getCacheDir()`) to make a copy of the content. Then, upload the copy, deleting the copy when you are done.